Why has GIMP (2.10.38) text wrap suddenly stopped working?
While the question basically describes the problem, the attached image is worth another thousand words.
Leading up to the sudden appearance of this bug, neither my LINUX nor GIMP versions had changed in many years. (Which is why installing GIMP 2.10.38 did not fix the problem).
Something external to GIMP itself may have changed - I personally suspect something related to the font.


Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I can't reproduce this behaviour. Perhaps try updating GIMP. That's quite an old version now. The latest is now 2.10.38

As I suspected, installing 2.10.38 makes no difference whatsoever.

Then I'm at a loss. I can't reproduce the problem. Granted I'm using Windows.  Could it be a bug perhaps in the Linux version?  Maybe better to report it.

... and it only happens with SOME .xcf files. I'm trying to find something odd about those affected. I would be great to recreate the problem at will before reporting to the team.
